# Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$. Then is $f$ uniformly continuous on $(0,3)?$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

1. Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$. Then is $f$ uniformly continuous on $(0,3)?$
2. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[n,n+1] \; \forall n\in N$, then is $f$ necessarily continuous on $[1, \infty]$?

for 1. take $x_n, y_n \in (0,3) $ such that $|x_n-y_n| \to 0$

then case 1. both $x_n, y_n \in (0,2) $ so $f$ uniform continuous on $(0,2)$ gives that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \to 0$

case 2. similar if both belong to $(1,3)$, we're done

case 3. if both of them don't belong to same set among $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$ (eventually),
then they must belong to $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ in which ever order, so$ |x_n - y_n| $ never tends to $0$ in this case.

is this argument correct?

also please help me for 2. I don't have any idea how to do this.

Comment: Almost correct. In case 3, the intervals are rather $(0,1]$ and $[2,3)$. Also, you should spell out that '*(eventually)*', preferably before splitting to the 3 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number two, $f(x)=x^{2}$ is uniformly continuous on any compact interval, but it is not uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: is part 1. correct?

Comment: Sounds good actually.